# Angular.js - <md-backdrop> may not work properly in a scrolled, static-positioned parent container

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

I'm currently working on an Angular.js 1.5 application with Angular Material. I'm receiving the following error in the console:

> `<md-backdrop>` may not work properly in a scrolled, static-positioned parent container.

I'm attempted to pinpoint the error in my markup, but I cannot find what is triggering the error.

I'm not sure what could I should provide to help clarify my error. Does anyone have any ideas what is triggering the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by an `<md-sidenav>` element within a static parent container (as the error message stated).

To solve this, I added the `md-disable-backdrop="true"` attribute and the error no longer occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add below css. This has solved my problem.

`body{
top: 0px !important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

parent element of md-dialog -> change position anything other than static

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing this line after adding angular-material.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this warning while opening md-dialog, then just remove the **parent** property from `$mdDialog.show({})`. Then you won't get this warning.